# Prevent multiple inclusions in perl

Tags: perl, module

Suppose I have two files: a module file that looks like this:

```
package myPackage;
use Bio::Seq;
```

and another file that looks like this:

```
use lib "path/to/lib";
use myPackage;
use Bio::Seq;
```

How can i prevent that Bio::Seq is included twice? Thanx

Comment: what actual problem are you having?

Comment: I want to - and here comes the question: prevent that Bio::Seq is included twice!!!!

Comment: It's loaded into memory once and imported twice, once in each package namespace. Your code already does what you want.

Comment: @sdir: But, as `ysth` asked, *what actual problems are you having?* With `use` and `require` a `*.pm` file is read and executed only one per process. What are you trying to fix?

Comment: @sdir: Dear `sdir` we try hard to help people, so both `ysth` and I asked *what problem are you trying to solve*? You presumably have a problem that you thought including `Bio::Seq` just once instead of many times would help to fix. Please tell us what problem that is and we will gladly help you. As you now understand, your guess at a solution will not help.

Comment: And I said that it is answered. Coming from a C background I assumed 'used' modules are included. Some here were clever enough to point my failure out. Some weren't. Also: the question has an accepted answer!

Comment: I asked because it was possible you were getting import naming conflicts (caused by other code not shown); glad all is well now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use Foo`

is mostly equivalent to

```
# perldoc -f use
BEGIN { 
    require "Foo.pm";
    Foo->import();
}
```

And `require "Foo"` is mostly equivalent to

```
# perldoc -f require
sub require {
  my ($filename) = @_;
  if (exists $INC{$filename}) {
    return 1 if $INC{$filename};
    die "Compilation failed in require";
  }
  # .... find $filename in @INC
  # really load
  return do $realfilename;
}
```

So

No, the code won't be "Loaded" more than once, only "imported" more than once.

If you have code such as

```
package Bio::Seq;
...
sub import { 
  # fancy stuff
}
```

And you wanted to make sure a library was loaded, but **not** call `import` on it,

```
#perldoc -f use
use Bio::Seq ();
```

Comment: @KentFrederic: No! `use` is *It is exactly equivalent to* `require` plus `import`

Comment: Yes, but somewhere between 'use' and 'require' ( at least, as far as the documentation is concerned ) your bareword string of the module name is translated into a path via `s{::}{/}`

Comment: @KentFrederic: No. `require` accepts the same format as `use` for its parameter. The only difference is that `use` has an implied `BEGIN` block around it and executes `PACKAGE->import`. I am being particularly picky because your answer will be found by people searching Stack Overflow for information on this topic. Can you offer a reference that says that `require` resolves the package name into a file path before it is passed to `use`?

Comment: Yes, but the documentation for 'require' doesn't show how that works, the mocked model it has there only compensates for parsing the string, not the bareword form.  Also, my name has no 'e' between the 'd' and the 'r'.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. For the world, the documentation for `use` says that it is *exactly equivalent* to `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }` and [this is the current documentation for `require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). As far as I can tell it talks about bareword module names properly but could use an update. I can see nothing that excuses your *"is mostly equivalent to "*. If you see a documentation bug then please report it using `perlbug`.

Comment: not quite; the import is skipped if `()` is explicitly specified for LIST, the call is more like `'Module'->import`, and if a version is given, a version check is done before the import: `'Module'->VERSION( VERSION )`

Comment: `q{ require Module } ne q{ require "Module.pm" }`  and `q{ import() } ne q{ ->import(LIST) }`

Comment: @ysth: Are you saying that `use PACKAGE ()` is the same as `BEGIN { require PACKAGE }` and different from `BEGIN { require PACKAGE; PACKAGE->import() }`? If so then I am surprised and inclined to disbelieve you. If you are right then you should submit a documentation bug as a matter of urgency.

Comment: yes, I am saying that.  and that is what the documentation says (though not in the summary at the top).

Answer (score 3):

It won't be included twice. `use` semantics could be described like that:

1. `require` the module
2. call module's `import`

As the documentation says, it's equivalent to:

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module−>import( LIST ); }
```

`require` mechanism, on the other hand, assures modules' code is **compiled and executed only once**, the first time some require it. This mechanism is based on the special variable `%INC`. You can find further details in the [documentation for `use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), and in the [perlmod page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html).

Comment: A clear answer and without a long string of comments :D .  I would add that the [`require` docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) specifically say: "Note that the file will not be included twice under the same specified name."

Answer (score 2):

Modules aren't "included" in Perl like they are in C. They are "loaded", by which I mean "executed".

A module will only be loaded/executed once, no matter how many `use` statements specify it.

The only thing that happens for every `use` of a module is the call to the module's `import` method. That is typically used to export symbols to the using namespace.

Comment: *"The only thing that happens for each `use` is the call to the module's import method"* is far from true. What happens is that definitions are defined and executable statements are executed.

Comment: @Borodin, That's completely false. Those two things only happen the first time the module is used.

Comment: What? Are you saying that, *"each use of a module"* excludes *"the first time the module is used"*? You are very wrong here, and that is inexcusable in this environment.

Comment: @Borodin, No, I don't. It calls `import` the first time too.

Comment: So you stand by *"The only thing that happens for [the first] use of a module is the call to the module's import method"*?

Comment: @Borodin, I never said that

Comment: **Your answer says** *"The only thing that happens for each use of a module is the call to the module's import method"*. If you mean by *each*, "all but the first" then please say so.

Comment: @Borodin, If something happens the first time but not the second time, it didn't happen both times. That something didn't happen each time doesn't mean that it didn't some of the times. You're applying negation improperly.

Comment: No, I don't mean all but first. `import` is called each time, not all but the first time.

Comment: @Borodin, You seem to think I said "Every use of a module results only in a call to the import method", and that's not what I said at all.

Comment: the only thing that happens for all, ie: the thing that applied for all, and is the only thing that applied for all.. `{ applied_to_all => [qw( import )],  only_the_first => [qw( require ]] }`

Comment: @ikegami: So by *"each"* you really do mean *"all but the first"*? So Perl's `each` doesn't do what you expect. And I should re-read all your posts in that light.

Comment: And no, if you interpret "each" as "all but the first", that would exclude `import` on the first `use`, but not on subsequent ones, which is *certainly not the case* and *certainly not what I read him to be saying*

Comment: Ahh! You must learn a little English. Your problem is primarily the use of `each` instead of `every` and the positioning of `only`. *The only thing that happens for each use of a module* is talking about *The only thing that happens*. What you mean is *The thing that happens only for each use of a module* or, preferably, *The only thing that happens for every use of a module*.

Comment: Its all about how you rank word precedence =P But I understood him the way he wrote it.

Comment: @KentFredric: Linguistically there was a missing `only` in the original. He meant *"The only thing that happens for only each use..."*. I genuinely didn't understand what he wrote, and I think the proper form is very clumsy. I have altered the English in the answer to read the way I believe it should.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you want to **optimize** the *loading*(usage) of  Module.

For optimizing, dynamic loading may be helpful.

For dynamically loading a Perl Module, we use [Class::Autouse](http://p3rl.org/Class%3a%3aAutouse).

For more details you can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470019/load-perl-modules-automatically-during-runtime-in-perl) link.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the OP may look for a way of avoiding a long list of `use` statement boilerplate at the beginning of his/her Perl script. In this case, I'd like to point everyone to [`Import::Into`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into). It works like the keyword `import` in Java and Python. Also, [this blog post](http://friedo.com/blog/2014/06/removing-boilerplate-with-importinto) provides a wonderful demo of `Import::Into`.